# How I use the data from Angular on Node JS? And how can I make a page load the information about a certain "data"?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I'm working on a project that I need from login, to compare the information at the form with the database. And later, after doing the validation, I need to load the information of a login in another page (I have no idea how).
(I tried to find some tutorials, but all of them use Express, that I'm not allowed to)

Now my code:

HTML (I think this part is OK, cause I could save the information in $scope.u)

```
<form ng-controller = "login" ng-submit="submit(user)">

    <label>Login:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.login"  required>
    <label>Senha:</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.pwd" required>
    <label><input type="checkbox"> Lembre-me</label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>

    <p>{{user.login}}</p>
    <p>{{user.pwd}}</p>
    <p>LOGIN:{{user.login}}</p>
    <p>SENHA:{{user.pwd}}</p>
</form>
```

Angular (I'm not sure if I understood the idea of $http.post, so I don't know if I can send the info of $scope.u to Nodejs)

```
app.controller('login',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.u = {};

    $scope.submit = function(user) {
        $scope.u = angular.copy(user);

        console.log($scope.u);
    };
    $http.post('/servico/login', $scope.u).success(function(data, status) {
        console.log('Data posted successfully');
    });
});
```

Node (If I could use the information of $scope.u, my problem would be finished there, but I don't know how I can load the information in another page)
The button Login should compare the values from the form and them, maybe, use  to send to the other page.

```
function login(request,response){
var queryString = 'SELECT uLogin,uSenha FROM usuarios';
connection.query(queryString,function(err,rows){

});

}
```

I hope I've been clear with my doubt. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your question is, but it seems like you are asking for help in creating a large chunk of application logic, or at least asking for a tutorial on how to perform your task.  Unfortunately this is off topic here.

Comment: If you can't use Express (which strikes me as an odd and silly limit) are there other packages you also can't use?